# What is the docs on layer display order when Flutter supports more than one shadow?

Tags: flutter

For example, I have the code below.

```dart
boxShadow: [
  BoxShadow(
    color: Color(    0xffff0000,),
    offset: Offset(4,4),
    blurRadius: 4,
    spreadRadius: 7,
  ),
  BoxShadow(
    color: Color(    0xff000000,),
    offset: Offset(10,4),
    blurRadius: 4,
    spreadRadius: 10,
  ),
]
```

The result is like this.

[image]

In other words, since the shadow layers are placed in the order of arrangement, the 0th layer is placed at the bottom.

However, I searched the flutter api and couldn't find anywhere that explains this.

Could you please point me to the relevant **documentation**?

flutter BoxShadow class docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxShadow-class.html

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c19845a8c3/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/box_decoration.dart#L431

Comment: @pskink Thank you so much for finding the code yourself!!